# Can't connect to server using samba. Error: Failed to mount windows share: No route to host

Tags: 18.04, samba

I'm trying to connect to my company server using samba, via nautilus. However, I get the following error: "Failed to mount windows share: No route to host".

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome, and nautilus. My colleagues can access the server with the same setup as me.

If I log into a ubuntu 16 installation it works just fine.

I tried reinstalling gnome, nautilus, and samba.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using lvm + btrfs filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that docker.service was causing this issue. I guess it is because the server ip that I was trying to access is in the range used by docker.

I disabled docker.service, rebooted and everything worked out. I will try to change the docker ip range and enable the service again, to make it possible to use both.